# Ceaser Cipher-Python, nested loops

Tags: python, python-2.7, rot13

```
word = ((raw_input("please enter the letters  ")).upper())
word = word.replace(" ","")
word.decode('utf-8', 'ignore')
wordlist = list(word.strip())
numberlist = []
newlist = []
num = 0

while num <= 13:
    for i in wordlist:    #conversion from letters to numbers
        numberlist.append(ord(i))

    for i in numberlist:    #bigger than Z check
        numberlist[numberlist.index(i)] = i + num+1
        if i >= 90:
            numberlist[numberlist.index(i)] = (i - 90) + 65

    for i in numberlist :
        newlist.append(chr(i))

    print ''.join(newlist)
    num += 1
    del newlist[:]
    del numberlist[:]
```

I am having problems branching loops on my 'for i in list:' loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two things wrong.

The 'list' variable isn't defined.

'for i in list:' won't run if it's not in your program.

Comment: nope the list acts like a function

Comment: The point I'm trying to make is that 'for i in list:' doesn't exist in your program.  Your question is poorly worded as you have three for loops for a type list and no mention of which one is giving you problems.  What specifically is your problem and with which loop?